# How to "Partial-Transpose-and-Duplicate" rows in a CSV with a CSV command line tool

Tags: csv, command-line-interface

I have again and again CSV files like this (formatted as a table):

```
| PRODUCT | REGION   | COMMENT  | SALES1   | SALES2  | SALES3 |
| ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | ------- | ------ |
| Orange  | Valencia | good     | Peter    |         |        |
| Apple   | Bavaria  | mediocre | Maria    | Walter  |        |
| Dates   | Dubai    | good     | Angelica | William | Jessie |
```

In this CSV I want to transpose the last three columns into one column while duplicating the information of the other columns, so that the result would look like this:

```
| PRODUCT | REGION   | COMMENT  | SALES    |
| ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Orange  | Valencia | good     | Peter    |
| Apple   | Bavaria  | mediocre | Maria    |
| Apple   | Bavaria  | mediocre | Walter   |
| Dates   | Dubai    | good     | Angelica |
| Dates   | Dubai    | good     | William  |
| Dates   | Dubai    | good     | Jessie   |
```

Of course I can write a little (Python) script to do this, but my question is:

**Is this somewhat a standard operation on tables/CSVs/matrices and can any of the existing CSV command line tools** (like `csvkit`, `miller`, `csvtool`, etc) **do this possibly out of the box?**

Comment: Does your input file is a CSV or a markdown?

Comment: Input is CSV, but if you need it as a markdown table as I formatted it, you can e.g. use `csvlook` from the _csvkit_ project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) starting from

```
PRODUCT,REGION,COMMENT,SALES1,SALES2,SALES3
Orange,Valencia,good,Peter,,
Apple,Bavaria,mediocre,Maria,Walter,
Dates,Dubai,good,Angelica,William,Jessie
```

and running

```
mlr --csv reshape -r "SALE" -o item,value then filter '$value=~".+"' then cut -x -f item then rename value,SALES input.txt
```

you will have

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| PRODUCT | REGION   | COMMENT  | SALES    |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Orange  | Valencia | good     | Peter    |
| Apple   | Bavaria  | mediocre | Maria    |
| Apple   | Bavaria  | mediocre | Walter   |
| Dates   | Dubai    | good     | Angelica |
| Dates   | Dubai    | good     | William  |
| Dates   | Dubai    | good     | Jessie   |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Ok, if it works, please mark this answer as the right one :)

Comment: Had to install Miller, but it works amazingly. Thanks again. I certainly will do more with Miller!